# Incorrect use of pixels of webpage

Tags: html, css

```css
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/******* RESET FINISHED BEYOND THIS POINT ******/

#header{
 background-color:#2098D1;
 color:white;
 padding-top:30px;

}

.group-wrapper{
 width:60%;
 margin:0 auto;
 overflow:hidden;
 position:relative;

 
}

.logo-name{
 line-height:1.4;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-family:arial;
 position:relative;
 float:left;
}

.logo-name h1{
 font-size:20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;

}

.logo-name h2{
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:normal;

}

#nav{
 float:right;
 

}

#nav ul{
 float:right;
 width:100%;
 font-family:arial;


}

#nav ul li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:10px;
 font-size: 15px;
}


.intro-company{
 background-color:#2098D1;
 color:white;
 padding-top:30px;
 height:250px;
}

.group-center{
 width: 60%;
 margin:0 auto;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:30px;
}


.group-center h1{
 font-size:48px;
 font-family:arial;
}

.group-center h2{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:23px;
 margin-top:20px;
}

.group-center h3{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:13px;
 margin-top:30px;
}


.content-wrapper{
 width:70%;
 margin:0 auto;
}

.main-content h1{
 text-align:center;
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:50px; 
}

.main-content span{
 font-weight: bold;
 color:#2098D1;
}

.content-wrapper{
 overflow:hidden;
 margin-top:50px;
}
.content-wrapper img{
 float:left;
 
}

.main-content{
 overflow:hidden;
}

.content-wrapper p{
 margin-top:20px;
 width:75%;
 margin-left:25%;
 line-height: 1.3em;
 font-family:arial;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:20px;
}

.my-skills{
 background-color:#2098D1;
}

.skills-wrapper{
 width:70%;
 margin:0 auto;
 margin-top:40px;
 color:white;
}

.my-skills h1{
 font-size:50px;
 margin-top:40px;
 text-align:center;
 font-family:arial;

}

.my-skills ul{
 text-align:center;

}
.my-skills ul li{
 text-align:center;
 list-style-type: none;
 display:inline-block;
}







/****** MEDIA QUERIES ******/





/****** SCREEN: 1115PX ******/
@media screen and (max-width: 1115px) {
#nav{
 float:none;

}

#nav ul{
 float:none;
}

#nav ul li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:10px;
 font-size: 10px;
 
 

}

.group-wrapper{
 width:70%;
 margin:0 auto;
 text-align:center;
 
 position:relative;
}

.group-center h1{
 font-size:45px;
 font-family:arial;
}

.group-center h2{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:22.5px;
 margin-top:18px;
}

.group-center h3{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:13.5px;
 margin-top:27px;

}

.logo-name{
 display:none;
}   

}



/****** SCREEN: 1115PX ******/
@media screen and (max-width: 705px) {



.group-center h1{
 font-size:40px;
 font-family:arial;
}

.group-center h2{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:19.5px;
 margin-top:18px;
}

.group-center h3{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:11px;
 margin-top:27px;

}

.logo-name{
 display:none;
}
  
}


/****** SCREEN: 1115PX ******/
@media screen and (max-width: 609px) {



.group-center h1{
 font-size:35px;
 font-family:arial;
}

.group-center h2{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:16.5px;
 margin-top:18px;
}

.group-center h3{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:9px;
 margin-top:27px;

}

.logo-name{
 display:none;
}


 
   
}


/****** SCREEN: 1115PX ******/
@media screen and (max-width: 609px) {

.group-center h1{
 font-size:30px;
 font-family:arial;
}

.group-center h2{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:13.5px;
 margin-top:18px;
}

.group-center h3{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:7px;
 margin-top:27px;

}

.logo-name{
 display:none;
}  
}
```

```html
<title>My website</title>
</head>

<body>

<header id = "header">
 <div class = "group-wrapper">
  <div class = "logo-name">
   <h1>NAME HERE</h1>
   <h2> INFO HERE</h2>
  </div>

  <nav id = "nav">
   <ul>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>PORTFOLIO</li>
    <li>TESTIMONIALS</li>
    <li>ARTICLES</li>
    <li>HIRE JAMES</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>

 </div>
</header>

<div class = "intro-company">
 <div class = "group-center">
  <h1>WordPress / Front-end Developer</h1>
  <h2>Producing high quality responsive websites and exceptional user experience</h2>
  <h3>VIEW PORTFOLIO</h3>
 </div>
</div>
```

I've made the transition from using ***'%*'** to **'px'*** and I'm having a bit of bother. I found percentages far easier in the sense you know it'll fit each screen as the percentage is relative to the individual viewport.

Whereas when I'm using ***'px'*** I find myself not truly understanding what they represent. For example, I'm now in the process of creating a portfolio website - I've just the top half, and it looks rather nice. However I've clearly not used pixels correctly because when the screen lessens half of the width cuts off.

The code snippet demonstrates exactly what I mean.

```css
tml, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

body {
    line-height:1;
}

article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section { 
    display:block;
}

nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}

blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}

blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}

a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}

/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000; 
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}

del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}

abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}

table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}

/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;   
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}

input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}

/******* RESET FINISHED BEYOND THIS POINT ******/

#header{
 background-color:#2098D1;
 color:white;
 padding-top:30px;
}

.group-wrapper{
 width: 1120px;
 margin:0 auto;
 
 position:relative;
 
}

.logo-name{
 line-height:1.4;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 font-family:arial;
}

.logo-name h1{
 font-size:20px;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 margin-right:30px;

}

.logo-name h2{
 font-size:15px;
 font-weight:normal;
 margin-right:30px;
}

#nav{
 float:right;
 position:relative;
 margin-left:120px;
}

#nav ul{
 float:right;
 width:100%;
 font-family:arial;


}

#nav ul li{
 display:inline-block;
 margin-right:10px;
 font-size: 15px;
}


.intro-company{
 background-color:#2098D1;
 color:white;
 padding-top:30px;
 height:250px;
}

.group-center{
 width: 1120px;
 margin:0 auto;
 position:relative;
 text-align:center;
 margin-top:30px;

}

.group-center h1{
 font-size:50px;
 font-family:arial;
}

.group-center h2{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:25px;
 margin-top:20px;
}

.group-center h3{
 font-family:arial;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:15px;
 margin-top:30px;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
 <meta charset=utf-8>
 <title>My website</title>
</head>

<body>

<header id = "header">
 <div class = "group-wrapper">
  <div class = "logo-name">
   <h1>Name</h1>
   <h2> Some information</h2>
  </div>

  <nav id = "nav">
   <ul>
    <li>ABOUT</li>
    <li>PORTFOLIO</li>
    <li>TESTIMONIALS</li>
    <li>ARTICLES</li>
    <li>HIRE JAMES</li>
   </ul>
  </nav>

 </div>
</header>

<div class = "intro-company">
 <div class = "group-center">
  <h1>WordPress / Front-end Developer</h1>
  <h2>Producing high quality responsive websites and exceptional user experience</h2>
  <h3>VIEW PORTFOLIO</h3>
 </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The best way is a blend of %, px and vh/vw. Why are you "transitioning"? As far as I know it is not best practice to avoid %

Comment: Not sure why you're wanting to transition? Are you not wanting to make your site responsive? Px are good for some things, but you should mix them in with em, %, etc. where appropriate to create more nuanced design.

Comment: Pixels represent an actual value, whereas percents are obviously relative. It's like setting an element's width to 5 centimeters - no matter what changes around it, you specified that you want it to be 5 centimeters. It will not change.

Comment: @CalvT븃 don't forget about `em` and `rem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using pixels (**px**) is that it never changes, regardless of the screen size. Percents(%) take into account the width of the screen and resize the elements accordingly.

For example: Say you have the following code

```
<body>
  <div style="width: 50%;">
    <p>The width of this div will be 50% of the width of the body</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

If the width of the body is, say, 1000px, then the width of the div will be 500px, because 500 is half of 1000 (or 1000 / 2 = 500). If you set the width of the div to 500**px**, then it would always stay at 500px, even if the width of the body is less than 500px.

Removing the width property from your .group-wrapper and .group-center classes like so will get rid of this problem.

```
.group-wrapper {
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
}

.group-center{
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
text-align:center;
margin-top:30px;
}
```

The same thing applies with the height property. When you resize the screen/window down to a mobile phone size, the height of the .intro-company class does not increase because you have its height set to 250px. Removing the `height: 250px;`will fix this problem as well.

The reason you can simply remove the `height: 250px;` is because the height will always increase to fit the content inside of it.

Revise your .intro-company code to:

```
.intro-company{
background-color:#2098D1;
color:white;
padding-top:30px;
}
```

**EDIT**: I just want to point out that when you're developing your website/webpage for smaller screens like a mobile phone, you should add this code somewhere in your  tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Looking closely, the `width=device-width` makes it so that the width of the page stays the same as the width of the screen width. The `initial-scale=1.0`sets the zoom level for the browser.

More information can be found here https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: I don't see a question that you are giving an answer to.

Comment: How? I explain how % and px work with examples right in his webpage

Comment: What question are you answering? I don't see a question.

Comment: I felt that he did not understand when he said "I find myself not truly understanding what they represent." I thought that that was the reason for this post

Comment: Or is he wanting to figure out how to keep his element on screen? We don't know.

Comment: I see what you're saying, but I think I helped him understand.

Comment: @Rob I see what you're saying the question itself was very poorly asked, and could have definitely been worded better.

Comment: @Alex Thanks a lot, mind if I show you a code snippet of how I've re-done it, just want to find your opinion on its responsiveness?

Comment: @James Sure thing

Answer (score 0):

percentages are great and can make building responsively quick and easy but I still use px all the time. They're very useful when you want a defined, unchanging size. The choice is whether you're going for responsive or adaptive design. And I choose to go for hybrid design which is both responsive and adaptive. Somethings like the logo stay the same size until you get down to mobile then they snap down to a smaller size. Other things like grids are great to be set as %

For example say you have three boxes wrapped within a parent div:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

You want them all to be 33.333333333(recurring)% there's a much simpler way to do this with the `calc` function:

```
.child {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

As a little aside to get this working sometimes you have to set the parent divs font-size to 0 and then set font-size back to whatever you want it to be within the child divs.

Comment: What question are you answering?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of designers would say you're going the wrong direction - the trend has been *away* from fixed units like pixels and *toward* relative units like `%`, `vw`, and `vh`. This is for the exact reason you stated: fixed units might make a design look perfect on your screen, but on any other screen size, might look terrible. It only gets worse as the difference in screen size widens - think phones and tablets.

On the other hand, it takes more effort to do it with relative units. Creating a pixel-perfect layout *with pixels* is relatively straightforward; creating a responsive design that transitions smoothly between viewport sizes takes a lot more work, skill, and generally a lot of trial and error. The benefit, of course, is that it doesn't completely fall apart in different viewport sizes.

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer to the question. And that's really bad since there isn't a question by the poster in the first place.